# Any suggestions on why the triangle is not rotating when I press a key?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I am looking for an answer to why the triangle is not rotating when I press a key.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Beta extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int LEFT = 0, RIGHT = 1;

    Beta()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        repaint(); // call superclass's paintComponent
```

points of the triangle

```
        int[] xPoints = {-50, 0, 50};
        int[] yPoints = {0, -50, 0};

        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        GeneralPath star = new GeneralPath(); // create GeneralPath object

        // set the initial coordinate of the General Path
        star.moveTo(-50, 0);

        // create the star--this does not draw the star
        for ( int count = 1; count < xPoints.length; count++ )
          star.lineTo( xPoints[ count ], yPoints[ count ] );

        star.closePath(); // close the shape

        g2d.translate( getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 ); // translate the origin to (150, 150)

        // rotate around origin and draw stars in random colors
```

rotate

```
        g2d.rotate( Math.PI / 40.0 );

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        g2d.fill( star );
    }

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

press key to draw

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
{
    switch(ke.getKeyCode())
    {   
        default: repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Space Battle Beta" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

            //add Panel to frame
        Beta shapes2JPanel = new Beta(); 
        frame.add( shapes2JPanel ); // add shapes2JPanel to frame
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setSize( 315, 330 ); // set frame size
        frame.setVisible( true ); // display frame
    }
} // end class Shapes2JPanel
```

Cannot make triangle rotate.
Is `repaint()` not working or is it something else?

Comment: You also need a Swing Timer in there to advance variables that the degree of rotation is based on and trigger repainting. Also, consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for a better quicker answer.

Comment: Please see Edit 2 in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

repaint() will not call the superclass's paint method, it will call this class's one. you should do `super.paintComponent(g)` to call the superclass's paintComponent() instead of `repaint()`

Comment: @Brennan: Regardless of whether this did not work, you must abide by this recommendation to erase any vestiges of previously drawn images. 1+ to James for a great suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using an AffineTransform to do your rotation, and doing this in a Swing Timer. Then use this in your paintComponent method to rotate a triangular `Shape` which can be your GeneralPath object (though I'd declare the GeneralPath variable in the class, not in paintComponent).

As for your call to repaint:

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    repaint(); // call superclass's paintComponent
```

You understand that this does nothing of the sort, and that if Swing weren't smart enough would cause an infinite recursion and lock your program. As mentioned by James, call the super's paintComponent method for this behavior.

**Edit 1:**
Also, you'll probably want to use Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener since it is a higher-level construct, and is more flexible with regard to focus -- a KeyListener will only work if the component that is being listened to has the focus, not so with key bindings if set up correctly.

**Edit 2:**
OK, this worked for me:

- Make star a Path2D variable and again a class field and initialize it with your int[] arrays for x and y values.
- Create a Swing Timer variable, I called rotateTimer, and make it a class field
- Use the Path2D method `transform(AffineTransform at)` and a AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty) to center your triangle on your JPanel.
- Use two key bindings to bind to the KeyEvent.VK_R key. I would use the KeyStroke.getKeyStroke method that takes 2 ints and a boolean to bind to both key pressed and key released.
- In the AbstractAction for key pressed (onKeyRelease is false), start() your timer
- And in the AbstractAction for key released (onKeyRelease is true), stop() your timer
- In the Swing Timer ActionListener's actionPerformed method again call `star.transform(AffineTransform at)`, but this time use an `AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(BASE_THETA, anchorx, anchory)` that takes 3 doubles so you can tell it how far to rotate and center the axis of rotation around your star shape.
- In paintComponent all you need to do is cast Graphics to Graphics2D, and use the Graphics2D object to set the RenderingHints so that anti-aliasing is on, set your star's color and draw the star, that's it.

Comment: +1 for valuable guidance. @Brennan: You may like to study this related [example](http://rabbitbrush.frazmtn.com/asteroids.html) to see how the author addresses the focus problem when using a `KeyListener`.